# Can someone check over my VB.net code? Issue explained below

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access-2010

Okay I have created a log in system on VB.net using a database on access. The problem I am having is that some of the username and password combinations work perfectly, but some of them, although put in correctly, don't work at all. This is the code I have written...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' Check if username or password is empty
    If textpassword.Text = "" Or textusername.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields..", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        ' Both fields were supplied
        ' Check if user exist in database
        ' Connect to DB
        Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\database1.accdb"

        'conn.Open()
        'MsgBox("Susscess")

        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE username='" & textusername.Text & "' AND password = '" & textpassword.Text & "'"
        Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)

        'Open Database Connection
        sqlCom.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()

        Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

        If sqlRead.Read() Then
            MemberPage.Show()
            Me.Hide()

        Else
            ' If user enter wrong username and password combination
            ' Throw an error message
            MessageBox.Show("Username and Password do not match..", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

            'Clear all fields
            textpassword.Text = ""
            textusername.Text = ""

            'Focus on Username field
            textusername.Focus()
        End If 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Best to avoid concatenated strings for sql statements or you can risk sql injection issues. Also worth including `Using` structure to better manage object disposal. Should your '.Read' method rather be checking .'HasRows' or something similar?

Comment: Can you clarify what happens when they *"don't work at all"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that some mistake is happening at the condition you checking after filling the `dataReader`. i.e

```
If sqlRead.Read() Then
```

try the `if` condition by following code

```
If Not sqlRead Is Nothing  Then
```

if it doesnt work then..

I would suggest you to do it using `DataAdapter` and check whether it returns rows. if the row count is greater than 1 , you must show the `MemberPage`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    If textpassword.Text = "" Or textusername.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields..", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else

        Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\database1.accdb"


        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE username='" & textusername.Text & "' AND password = '" & textpassword.Text & "'"
        Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)

        Dim ds As DataSet

        sqlCom.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()

        'Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

        Dim da as New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCom)

        da.Fill(ds)

        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 1  Then
            MemberPage.Show()
            Me.Hide()

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("Username and Password do not match..", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)


            textpassword.Text = ""
            textusername.Text = ""


            textusername.Focus()
        End If 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not Concatenate string.Its wide open for SQL injection .Its better to use Parameterized query

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE username=? AND password = ?"
Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", textusername.Text);
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", textpassword.Text);
```

Also you can use `HasRows`  property

```
If sqlRead.HasRows Then
      While sqlRead.Read() 
       MemberPage.Show()
       Me.Hide()
      End While
 Else
     MessageBox.Show("Username and Password do not match..", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) 'Clear all fields
        textpassword.Text = ""
        textusername.Text = "" 
      'Focus on Username field
        textusername.Focus()
 End If
```